# angular cli lazy global style path in production build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

So angular-cli has a way to output multiple stylesheets if you use configuration like:

```
....
"styles": [
  "../styles/app.scss",
  { "input": "../styles/print.scss", "lazy": true, "output": "print" },
],
....
```

This in turn will generate `print.bundle.css` in build dir for dev and `print.{some-hash}.bundle.css` for prod provided that you pass `--extract-css` flag.

How can one load this stylesheet in production at runtime?

I just don't see a way to get the name to create a `<link>` tag correctly.

Basically I need this for print and `CKEditor` IFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the hashcode in the generated filename. To prevent this, use the `--output-hashing=media` or `--output-hashing=none` flag on production builds.